# Erro do Google Maps (Esta página não carregou o Google Maps corretamente)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ultimamente, todos os sites que criei e usei o maps, está aparecendo essa mensagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabem se mudou alguma coisa no google? alguma configurações na API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
de acordo com este [link](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?__utma=102347093.727060274.1537312141.1537312173.1537312173.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1537312173&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1537312173.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=124322058&_ga=2.151762361.1073750220.1537312175-727060274.1537312141)

O google maps requer uma chave para todos os seus projetos, desde **11 de junho de 2018** ;).

Parte que fala sobre isso:

> A partir de 11 de junho de 2018, você precisará ativar o faturamento com um cartão de crédito. Além disso, será necessário ter uma chave de API válida para todos os projetos.

Comment: entendi, mas pelo que entendi, tem um credito mensal ne?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, acredito que de imediato você terá que adicionar um cartão de credito e ativá-lo no painel do google maps, isso está sendo colocado nas documentações deles e **em destaque**.

Comment: Sim e nao. Vc tem um credito "gratuito", bem suficiente se vc faz só visualização das mapas. Se vc quer calcular tempo de viagem, rotas etc... vc tem também um pouco de credito, mas vc vai consumir e vc vai precisar pagar. Vai no site https://developers.google.com/ para ler tudo tranquilamente porque é um "pouco" confuso!!